# Expand the $f(x) = x\sin x$ in a Taylor series in powers of $(x + 1)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

These are my actions but I'm not sure, because x stayed and I couldn't find $f^{(103)}(-1)$
$\begin{align}f(x)&=x\sin((x+1)-1)\\&=x\left(\sin(x+1)\cos1 + \cos(x+1)\sin 1\right)\\&=x\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n (x+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n-1)!}\cos 1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n (x+1)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\sin 1\right)\end{align}$

Comment: Try writing $f(x)$ as $((x+1)-1)\sin((x+1)-1)$ instead of just $x\sin((x+1)-1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This look correct but you should write also $x=(x+1)-1 $ and then you obtain $$f(x) =\cos 1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (x+1)^{2n+2} }{(2n+1)!} +\sin 1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (x+1)^{2n+1} }{(2n)!} -\cos 1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (x+1)^{2n+1} }{(2n+1)!}- \sin 1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (x+1)^{2n} }{(2n)!} $$

So $\frac{f^{(103)} (-1)}{103!}$ is equal to a coefficint in the above sries which stay with $(x+1)^{103} $ hence $$\frac{f^{(103)} (-1)}{103!}=\sin1 \frac{(-1)^{51}}{102!} -\cos1\frac{(-1)^{51}}{103!}$$
$$f^{(103)} (-1)=-103\sin1 +\cos 1$$

Comment: Thank you so much!